# Test when recursion limit is reached in python

Tags: python, recursion

Is there a way to test when a program's recursion limit is reached? For example:

```
def funct():
    print "Hello"
    #Some code for testing the recursion limit.
        #Some more code to execute
```

If you are wondering why I want to know this, here is why: I want to hide an Easter egg in a program, but I can't do that until I found out how to do what I am asking. So, how can I test when the recursion limit is reached? Is there even a way?

Comment: Mind sharing with us why on earth you would want to test out that limit?

Comment: @Assaf_Lavie wait, what? I said the reason as to why I wanted to know this.

Comment: You want users to reach the easter egg? Or developers who read the code? I can't think of a good reason to actually allow production code to reach a state where it emits a stack overflow exception. Just use Konami code or something :)

Comment: @Assaf_Lavie it is the users who will reach the Easter egg. It would be something funny like printing a fake error message, or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for the `RuntimeError` like any other error, with `try`:

```
def funct():
    ...
    try:
       funct()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if "recursion" in e.message:
            print("Easter egg!")
```

Note that I've added an extra check that the error is warning about recursion, so you don't prevent any other `RuntimeError`s from going about their business.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are setting recursion measures on OpenAI here is the code snippet

```py
from openai import OpenAI, RateLimitError
import time

api_key = "your_api_key_here"
client = OpenAI(api_key)

try:
    # Your OpenAI API request here
    response = client.embeddings.create(...)
except RateLimitError as e:
    print(f"Rate limit exceeded. Waiting for {e.reset} seconds.")
    time.sleep(e.reset)
    # Retry your request or handle accordingly
```